# Inverse Trigonometry Plots ArcT(T(x))-Clarification

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJY6s.gif)

The graphs are plots of functional forms $T^{-1}(T(x))$ where T is a trigonometric function:sine,cosine,tangent,cosecant,cotangent,and secant

Can someone please explain me indivially case by case why is the nature of the plots periodically changing in this manner,should'nt all of them be just straight lines? Please help me clarify this doubt.Also how would $T(T^{-1}(x))$ 's graphs be?

Comment: $ \arcsin(k)$ will ouput numbers in $[-\frac{\pi}{2} ,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ .So this means we need to manipulate or make sure the number $x$ in $\arcsin(\sin(x))$ is a number in $[-\frac{\pi}{2} ,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ before we can say $\arcsin(\sin(x))=x$ . So for example $\arcsin(\sin(\pi))=\arcsin(\sin(0))=0$ So you will have point $(\pi,0)$ on your graph. Tried to plot other points on the graph of $f(x)=\arcsin(\sin(x))$. You should see you get your first graph that you have above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that a trig functions is periodic, therefore not one-to-one. So the corresponding "inverse trig" function is only an inverse for the function on a certain interval.  Thus  $\arcsin(y)$ is the value $x$ in the interval $-\pi/2 \le x \le \pi/2$ such that $\sin(x)=y$. If $-\pi/2 \le x \le \pi/2$ we have $\arcsin(\sin(x)) = x$, but this can't be the case for $x$ outside that interval. 
 As $x$ goes from  $\pi/2$ to $3\pi/2$, $\sin(x)$ decreases from $1$ to $-1$, and thus $\arcsin(x)$ decreases from $\pi/2$ to $-\pi/2$.  That gives you this part of the graph:

[image]

And then because $\sin$ is periodic with period $2\pi$, the pattern is repeated.